# Minimizing an application into tray

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

I am not sure of what I'm doing wrong here:

```
private void MainWindow_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) 
{
      var ni = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
      {
            Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("Img/trayicon.ico"), 
            Visible = true
      };

      this.Hide();
      e.Cancel = true;
}
```

When the user tries to close the window, MainWindow_OnClosing is triggered via Closing="MainWindow_OnClosing" in the xaml. There, I cancel the closing with e.Cancel = true and attempt to hide the window into a tray icon with the rest of the code above. But all that happens is that the content of the window is filled with a black color and thats it.

Upon clicking the close button the debug console prints out
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

But I am not sure if that has to do anything with it, since I know the icon picture exists within that folder in the project.

Comment: I would also notice, you're creating an icon and not doing anything with it.

Comment: Well damn, it does. But how is that possible? The icon is in the project's folder and is set as resource.

Comment: I don't think that's the way you're accessing resources.

Comment: I access them like this all over my application and it works everywhere for example " <Image Source="Img/arrows.png" />" in the xaml part of the file works no problem. And arrows.png is also set as resource the same way as the tray icon is.

Comment: You forgot `UriKind.Relative`.